# How to remove newline between text in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I have a `shipping_tablerate` table contains 1 million records. I have multiple texts in `suburb` column. Every suburb contains between the double hyphen(--) and newline. I want to remove all the new line between the suburb. 

Below is my query. That one was not working.

```
UPDATE  shipping_tablerate
 SET `suburb`=REPLACE(`suburb`,'\n','');
```

My current `suburb` column text is

```
BRISBANE--
BRISBANE ADELAIDE STREET--
BRISBANE CITY--
BRISBANE GPO--
SPRING HILL
--
```

I want

```
BRISBANE--BRISBANE ADELAIDE STREET--BRISBANE CITY--BRISBANE GPO--SPRING HILL--
```

Comment: Your code looks correct for standard newlines -- but what kind of newlines are you using?
Try `REPLACE(suburb,'\r\n','')` or `REPLACE(convert(suburb using utf8) ,'\r','')`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

REPLACE should work. Try replacing the \r character as well.

```
UPDATE shipping_tablerate SET suburb = REPLACE(REPLACE(suburb,'\n',''), '\r', '');
```

If that too doesn't work, try TRIM function:

```
UPDATE shipping_tablerate SET suburb = TRIM('\n' FROM suburb);
```